# 'gpiod' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, orange-pi, libgpiod

I'm trying to use libgpiod in python on my orangepi model 4B. I installed it with:

```
sudo apt install libgpiod-dev python3-libgpiod
```

Now I try to use it:

```
from gpiod.line import Direction, Value
```

But I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gpiod.line'; 'gpiod' is not a package
```

If I open python in terminal and import gpiod the autocomplete options for `gpiod.` are:

```
gpiod.Chip(                      gpiod.LINE_REQ_FLAG_OPEN_DRAIN
gpiod.ChipIter(                  gpiod.LINE_REQ_FLAG_OPEN_SOURCE
gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_AS_IS         gpiod.Line(
gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_IN            gpiod.LineBulk(
gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_OUT           gpiod.LineEvent(
gpiod.LINE_REQ_EV_BOTH_EDGES     gpiod.LineIter(
gpiod.LINE_REQ_EV_FALLING_EDGE   gpiod.find_line(
gpiod.LINE_REQ_EV_RISING_EDGE    gpiod.version_string(
gpiod.LINE_REQ_FLAG_ACTIVE_LOW
```

If I install gpiod through pip it says `module 'gpiod' has no attribute 'Chip'` when I try to use gpiod.Chip.

What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you install gpiod though pip what version version you get?

Comment: Typo error spelling Typo error `sudo apt istall`. should be `sudo apt install`

Comment: @EdherCarbajal 1.5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libgpiod-dev` includes the the [libgpiod C lib](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/about/) and its header files, while `python3-libgpiod` includes the Python bindings to that lib. So with the command:

```
sudo apt istall libgpiod-dev python3-libgpiod
```

You're installing the libgpiod lib, C headers and python bindings. This lib is an abstraction layer to use gpio char device in Linux.
Examples for controlling gpios with these python bindings can be found [here](https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/tree/master/bindings/python/examples).

Try copy-paste one of the examples and run it.
Make sure package is installed correctly and you have properly configured char device interface (`ls /dev` here you must see `gpiochipX` devices). I just tested it and worked as expected.

NOTE:

When you use `pip install gpiod` you can't use `gpiod.Chip`, but you can use `gpiod.chip` instead (note that the former is capital). This is because you are using an old version of gpiod python package.
You said that you're using gpiod version 1.5.4 so [this](https://pypi.org/project/gpiod/1.5.4/) is the corresponding documentation for that version. As you can see it claims to be a:

> It is a pure Python library and has no dependencies on other packages !!

It also includes a link to the proper documentation site where you can see that the examples are using `gpiod.chip` instead of `gpiod.Chip`.

The new version of gpiod package (2.1.3) is not a pure python package but official bindings to libgpiod. as you can see in the proper [doc](https://pypi.org/project/gpiod/2.1.3/). This version DOES support the usage of `gpiod.Chip` as you can see in its examples.

So, how to be able yo use `gpio.Chip` through a pip installation?

```
pip install gpiod==2.1.3
```

This guarantees you use the new version

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/gpiod/
Then what is this? It has gpiod.Chip and gpiod.line but when I install it with pip - it has no gpiod.Chip

Comment: @Dmitry Check out my answer, I edited it to add solve your doubts. It may be confusing the first time, but basically gpiod python package was independent in the old version, but now gpiod python pkg contains the official bindings

Comment: thanks a lot, but my pip has no version 2.1.3 available. It looks like repositories on my system are too old.

Comment: Oh got it, then that's the reason why you are not able to use gpiod.Chip. Try reading the docs and the examples for the version 1.5.4 to see how to use the version you have. If my Answer solve your doubts consider mark it as accpeted

Comment: btw, I wouldnt suggest to install libgpiod-python and gpiod python packages in the same usr space. Both are imported in python as 'gpiod', so it may cause conflict.